# Por que usar tipo Racional?

Tags: programação-funcional, haskell, clojure

Por que linguagens como Haskell e Clojure adotam racionais como tipo? Por que eu usaria Racional ao invés do Float ou Double?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Float* e *Double* são tipos com ponto flutuante binário, por isso há problemas  de arredondamento. Muitos números com partes decimais não pode ser expressados exatamente. Os racionais não possuem este problema.

Mas o maior motivo é que certos problemas são melhor expressados por frações, em geral trabalham com valores inteiros divididos por outros inteiros com uma precisão fixa ou aritrária.